# What would happen if I cleared the data of my Gallery app?

Tags: gallery, samsung-galaxy-grand

The app says it's using 36.29 GB of data, even though I don't have nearly that much memory on my phone and SD card combined, so I want to get rid of this bug.

My phone is Samsung Galaxy Grand, and it's not rooted.

Comment: I would recommend backing up your photos and videos just in case before clearing the data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it safe to clear data for gallery?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/136871/is-it-safe-to-clear-data-for-gallery)

Answer (score -1):

I have suffered from same prob. Donn't worry, just clear the gallery app data.
When you restart app it takes some time to reload images & video's thumbnails.

Comment: Please add some detail and content, as it stands its not a very good answer.